Issue with Enter and Delete Keys Not Functioning Properly (Wayland vs. Xorg)
System Information:
Device: Lenovo ThinkPad (second-hand). It used Windows 11, but I installed Ubuntu.The key board used to have a German layout. I switched to English (USA).
OS: Ubuntu (recently updated), currently switching between Xorg and Wayland
Installed Input Management Tools: Autokey (GTK version)
Custom Shortcuts: I have encoded common keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, Ctrl+X, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+Z using Python and xdotool.
Problem Description:
I am experiencing intermittent issues with my Enter and Delete keys on my Lenovo ThinkPad. This problem seems to be tied to software and environment configuration, particularly between Xorg and Wayland. Here's a summary of the issue:
Initial Problems with Xorg:
I initially used Wayland, where both the Enter and Delete keys stopped working after a few months of normal operation.
I switched to Xorg, where the keys worked fine for several weeks. Then the problem started in Xorg too.
I switched to Wayland and the Nightmare Begins in a week.
After switching to Wayland, everything was smooth until I updated my system. After the update, the Enter and Delete keys stopped functioning again. This time, it takes about 20 minutes after starting the computer for these keys to start working.
The issue seems to worsen when running resource-heavy software or after closing and reopening the laptop.
Temporary Workaround – Switching Back to Xorg:
I decided to switch back to Xorg to check if it resolves the issue. However, I encountered a strange situation:
While logging into Xorg, I realized that I might not be able to press "Enter" after entering my password.
To my surprise, after entering my password, the Enter key worked perfectly.
This raised a suspicion that there may be a software conflict or setup error causing this behavior.
Other Observations:
Running commands like sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade, sudo apt autoremove, and sudo apt clean sometimes temporarily resolves the issue, but it eventually resurfaces.
The issue seems to occur after certain updates or heavy processes, but it does not affect all contexts (e.g., the virtual keyboard sometimes works, but not consistently in all applications, like VS Code).
The Enter and Delete keys work flawlessly in some contexts, like logging in after switching from Wayland to Xorg, but behave unpredictably in others.
Custom Shortcuts:
I’ve created custom shortcuts for keys like Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, and more using Autokey. I haven't found any other way of creating shortcuts. I couldn't create them normally in the system. They just didn't work. Autokey was the only way I tried that worked. All the custom shortcuts work perfectly fine now. These were set up when I was on Xorg and still exist in Wayland. I suspect that some of these configurations might be interfering with the keyboard functionality, though I'm unsure how.
Steps I've Taken So Far:
Switching between Wayland and Xorg has given temporary relief, but the problem persists across both environments.
Reinstalled input device drivers (xserver-xorg-input-libinput), but the issue remains.
Monitoring system resource usage via htop shows normal behavior, with CPU percentages rising briefly but nothing alarming.
Disabled unnecessary shortcuts to avoid potential conflicts with system defaults.
Request for Help: I’m seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue, as it seems to be related to conflicting software, updates, or incorrect configuration between Wayland and Xorg. If anyone has experienced similar problems or knows how to debug keyboard issues related to input handling in Ubuntu, I would greatly appreciate your insights.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release: 24.04
Codename: noble
Ubuntu Desktop system
